# Finding keys with a value in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a Python function that returns a list of keys in `aDict` with the value `target`. The list of keys should be sorted in increasing order. The keys and values in `aDict` are both integers. (If `aDict` does not contain the `target` value, program should return an empty list.) The keys are a,b,c. I get an error msg that says name 'a' not defined. Not sure why as I have declared a, b and c as integers.

```
def keysWithValue(aDict, target):
    '''
    aDict: a dictionary
    target: integer
    a:integer
    b:integer
    c:integer
    '''
    # Your code here  
    i=0
    j=0    
    if aDict[i]==5:
       list[j]=aDict[i]
       i+=1
       j+=1
    return list
```

Comment: That's not how variables work in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generator expression to compare your `target` with each of the values in your dict's `.items()` then, wrap that in a `sorted` call.

If the value is a single integer you can use `==`

```
def keysWithValue(aDict, target):
    return sorted(key for key, value in aDict.items() if target == value)

>>> d = {'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'a': 1, 'd': 1}
>>> keysWithValue(d, 1)
['a', 'b', 'd']
```

Or if the values are lists of integers you can use `in`

```
def keysWithValue(aDict, target):
    return sorted(key for key, value in aDict.items() if target in value)

>>> d = {'b': [1,2,3], 'c': [2,5,3], 'a': [1,5,7], 'd': [9,1,4]}
>>> keysWithValue(d, 1)
['a', 'b', 'd']
```

Comment: The OP stated "The keys and values in aDict are both integers".